# Binding up using data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I've an

```
ObservableCollection<Products> products
```

in my Model class and another

```
ObservableCollection<Foo> foo
```

in the ViewModel class.

I've binded the products to a Developer Express GridControl and I've a column in that grid that is a ComboBox.

How I can bind the *foo* collection in the ComboBox?

Here's the way I've binded the products to the GridControl

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Model.Products}" ...
```

Comment: did any answer work for you? You should mark the question as answered or add the answer if you've found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.foo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridControl}}}"/>
```

Comment: I've solved it like you suggested but using AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}} so the path can be "Path=ViewModel.Model.xxx"